# Use a CSV file to copy folders with files to another directory

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have a similar goal as to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794199/robocopy-or-xcopy-read-from-file) S.O. question.  What I am doing is using a CSV file as a list to copy folders from one location to another.

EG.  CSV file is:

```
SKULIST
123
124
125
126
```

I want to use the SKU codes in CSV file as input to copy directories with their contents to another location.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.  I've found a bunch of requests that are close to what I'm looking to do but I don't know enough to figure out how to change the code.

I only need to do this once hopefully so cmd is fine or .bat if easier.

EDIT:

I need to do this for about 5300 folders containing 24-64 .jpg files in each folder which is why doing this manually is not feasible.

EDIT2:

I photograph products for a company and we have about 8000 products that I need to upload to a server, about 3000 of which are already uploaded.  The only way I know which files are uploaded right now are through and excel file which I can use in reverse to determine which ones still need to be uploaded.  The photographs are arranged into folders which are named with the sku (eg. 1k123, 1k124, 1tsu3, 21et13, etc, etc...) and then they have 24-64 .jpg files within that folder which are named with a specific naming convention (SKU_##*##*##.jpg).  I have a drive with all the photograph folders in it, but it also includes about 3000/8000 SKUs that have already been uploaded.  The hope is to use excel to determine the remaining 5000 (I don't need help with that part at least).  And then using whatever file is best use that file with the 5000 "to be uploaded" list as input for the code to figure out which still need to be uploaded as opposed to going through a massive drive of 8000 folders and picking out the 5000 that still need to be uploaded.  I don't really have code yet as I have nearly no idea how to do this.  In the link they use `for /f "delims=, tokens=3" %i in ( c:\temp\foo.csv ) do echo %i` to test it will work and then alter with xcopy once results are correct and obviously I need to edit that but I'm not really sure where to start.  As I said any help is super appreciated - this will save my team so much work. Sorry for being slightly vague with descriptions - some of this is proprietary info I'm sure and it's part of my job.

I don't have direct access to the server so I have to bring a drive with the remaining 5000 SKU folders to be uploaded. That is the end goal. Copy the 5000 SKUs that still need uploading to a new directory then bring that directory on a drive to the server.

-Grant

Comment: Do you have a batch file which shows what you have so far?

Comment: It's always easier to provide examples and sample data for instance a few lines of your csv file and examples of what you want to do with the contents. Stops the query becoming a 20-questions session. Just edit the information into the question.

Comment: As above, tell us how you plan to use the terms in the file.

Comment: Since you have 8000 "folders" in total, your SKUs can't be 3-digit - there are only 1,000 combinations of 3 digits aailable - but that's the info you've given us. How does the `21et13` relate to the skus? is the `SKU` in the filename literally `SKU` or is it the not-3-digit-but-something-secret-SKU? Does the move occur against the SKU in the filename or the secret SKU in the directory name? What is the format of the data in the mysterious file of 3,000 already-loaded directories or files? How do these relate to the file repository you are using?

Comment: Are you sure that directories that have already been transferred haven't been modified since the transfer took place? Just post some representative data to clarify the situation. Edit it judiciously. Tell us that where you put SKU1 in your sample data, it's actually 1 to 5 digits, that the dashes in the .jpg names actually follow the SKU number, or don't or whatever. Until we can form a picture of what you are doing, we can't help in any significant way.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  As for the SKUs, they are 5 or 6 digits long, obviously the first example given with 3 digits was just that, an example.  The bottom line is the folders which are named with the SKU and the files within them need to stay the same as they are when copied.

I'm thinking of this in terms of what I think would be the easiest way to achieve my goal, but basically I need to pull 5000 specific folders from a drive that contains 8000 folders.  If you have another way of doing this by all means let me know.